# Need help to interpret Node2Vec grammar

Tags: machine-learning, classification, graph-neural-network

I am studying Link Prediction using Node2Vec refering to [a tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/01/link-prediction-how-to-predict-your-future-connections-on-facebook/) on the web. The following equation is what I don't understand. Why is it this way?

```
x = [(n2w_model[str(i)]+n2w_model[str(j)]) for i,j in zip(data['node_1'], data['node_2'])]
```

Can somebody explain what the above equation means?